# Stack Overflow new design

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What happened to Stack Overflow? is that the new design?

The site is missing some features like the text editor bar and code coloration. is that a bug? or it's just happening on my machine?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your previous visit date... and yes if you are visiting after a long, it has been changed

Comment: Can you provide your browser version and OS... and do you have any extensions/JavaScript enabled etc... sounds like you've got browser problems.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya yesterday it was like Meta Stack Overflow, today is completely different

Comment: meta uses different color scheme as compared to SO. I dint find any difference between yesterday and today.

Comment: @anouar.bag nothing major has changed on SO or MSO in a very long time.  If you are seeing a radical change since yesterday, it's likely something on your end?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm using windows7, FireFox 20.0

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: No new design. If you can't see things you saw before it's most likely JavaScript being blocked, open the console of your browser and see the errors there.

Comment: @anouar.bag your screenshot is of the mobile site.

Comment: If you're not on a mobile device, go to the bottom of the page and click on "full site". That should take you back.

Comment: why do you guys downvote?

Comment: I'm not using a mobile device

Comment: Okay, so do as I said and all should be back to normal.

Comment: @anouar.bag [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  Mostly likely the downvotes votes are saying "nothing has changed".

Comment: What can cause such thing to happen?

Comment: Any chance you've been testing mobile sites and changed the browser's user agent?

Comment: @psubsee2003 OK, this my first time here

Comment: @anouar.bag I figured that was the case.  Meta Rep generally doesn't count for much, so downvotes are more common and can often be used to express disagreement.  If you are interested, read this [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the mobile version of Stack Overflow, you may have accidentally clicked on the mobile link.

Go to the bottom of the page and click this button to get the desktop version back:

[image]

Comment: Must. Upvote. Freehand. Circles!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There is only one single circle.

Comment: @Antony It's a circle so nice, we're counting it twice.

Comment: @Antony one circle to rule them all!